# Placing tile on second layer results in wrong tile, or changes nearby tiles

Tags: tilemap, unreal-4, spritesheet, bug, blueprints

So I am working on a 2d game and running into strange behavior when trying to add tiles to a tile map.

The first layer seems to work fine but if I add a new layer it will always place the same tile regardless of which tile I choose from the palette. Sometimes placing a tile changes tiles that were already placed elsewhere. [Here is a video of the behavior](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y7J-HfdzlBDvU7EGC7kgCk9kNLaVBgCX/view?usp=sharing.), excerpted as a gif below:

[image: Animated example of placing tiles]

It looks like it might be related to this bug:

[UE-72279: Paper2D Tilemap doesn't render tiles correctly when more than one layer is added.](https://issues.unrealengine.com/issue/UE-72279)

How can I solve this issue, to control the placement of tiles on my second layer?

Comment: Please upload your video to "public hosts" such as YouTube or create an animated gif out of it. Links to user shares tend to be removed, making question much less complete.

Comment: Sorry I will keep that in mind next time.